# All the `Native Node modules` exist in Node.js, why there need to "install Native Node modules"?

Tags: node.js, electron

when I read this [document](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules)
I don't understand,

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

# Every time you run "npm install", run this:
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

before execute `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild`, whether we need to install third party package?
like `npm install axios`?

[using-native-node-modules#troubleshooting](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules#troubleshooting):

> If you installed a native module and found it was not working

1. if is, this "third party package" is not `Native Node modules`, right?
2. as all we know, all the `Native Node modules` exist in Node.js, why there need to "install Native Node modules" then rebuild it for Electron support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing node core modules with native node modules. Native just means the module is written in a compiled language like C++ and exists as machine code at the end while regular modules exist as Javascript code. An example would be the `bcrypt` module. Core modules on the other hand are built into node itself and, as you correctly said, therefore won't need to be installed separately, such as `fs`.